# Protractor: Error: TypeError: browser.getProcessedConfig is not a function

Tags: typescript, protractor

Typescript Conf.ts file:

```
    onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        spec: {
            displayStacktrace: false
        }
    }));
    return browser.getProcessedConfig()
        .then(function(config: any) {
            return config.suite;
        })
        .then(function(suite: any) {
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
                baseDirectory: suite + '/screenshot'
            }).getJasmine2Reporter());
        });
}
```

After compiling **Conf.js** and trying to run the test, error is:

```
[09:17:38] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[09:17:39] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: browser.getProcessedConfig is not a function
    at onPrepare (Conf.js:42:24)
    at q_1.Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/util.js:46:49)
    at Function.promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:682:9)
```

Comment: Show your protractor version. Did you try delete the `node_modules\protractor` folder and reinstall protractor?

Comment: @yong. Thanks I tried that.  protractor --version
Version 5.4.1   node_modules\protractor\package.json shows: "_from": "protractor@5.4.1",

Comment: @yong The error I get after that is:             .then(function(config: any) {
                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: The global object browser might not be created at this point. Simply calling into `import {browser} from 'protractor'` might not work. I would suggest just calling (and I'm probably going to get the syntax wrong) `const browser = require('protractor').browser;` This will prevent transpile to figure out what browser is and move on.

Comment: Please use high version nodejs,  what's your nodejs version?

Answer (score 0):

it works in my case:

```
import { browser, Config } from 'protractor';

// tslint:disable object-literal-sort-keys
export let config: Config = {
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60 * 1000,
    showColors: true
  },
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1
  },
  onPrepare: async () => {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    const myConfig = await browser.getProcessedConfig();
    console.log('Config');
    console.log(myConfig);
    ...
    ...
  },

  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  specs: [
    '../test/my-test.js'
  ]
};
```